# Editable, web-based line diagram

Tags: html, drag-drop

As part of my home automation project I need a "heating schedule".
I want to be able to set at what time of the day the temperature should be set to which value. Example: At 6am turn set thermostat to 23°C, at 9am to 14°C and at 4pm to 22°C. Between 10pm and 6am down to 14°C.
The schedule needs to be configured graphically in a web browser. I want to be able to delete and add new temperature/time events.

I had a look at Highcharts and Google Charts for creating simple line charts. Highcharts could be made draggable at least. But adding and deleting points seems to be tricky.

Surely there is something available!? I cannot find anything of much use, however. Sure I could handle mouse events and enhance my draggable highchart but I do not want to re-invent the wheel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an editable schedule myself. If anybody is interested:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6u0xdnn/4/embedded/result/

EDIT: June 2015

Moving points does not work anymore. Try this workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6u0xdnn/5/embedded/result/

(move mouse after releasing mouse button after moving point)